# How to "display an InputBox" everytime I press a specific cell in excel/vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pop-up inputBox when I press a specific Cell in Excel/VBA.

I tried to do a while loop with all the information about every cell stored in an array.

Comment: Take a look perhaps at the [Worksheet.SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event.

Comment: Please add more context. Including the code you wrote in your post might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with Worksheet Selection Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        InputBox ("HELLO")
    End If
End Sub
```